# Loading Image using Dot operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to load image using dot operator.

Consider this as my image url

```
  <img src={{GET_PROFILE_DATA.googleProfileData.fullName}} alt="profile" class="home-screen-profile-image">
```

Notice weird looking src here

```
src={{GET_PROFILE_DATA.googleProfileData.fullName}}
```

This is coming from

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Profile",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["GET_PROFILE_DATA"])
  }
};
</script>
```

**[Question:]** How to load image using dot operator?

Comment: You mean [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals). Notice, that the spread syntax for object literals is not a standard yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **bind** `src` to your property using `:src="property"` or `v-bind:src="property"`:

```
  <img :src="GET_PROFILE_DATA.googleProfileData.fullName" alt="profile" class="home-screen-profile-image">
```

(Note: No curly braces)

See [Vue Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for more details.